# How Can I bring my application to the Top of windows

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

> If I have two applications running simultaneously , App1.exe and App2.exe , I want to bring App2.exe when a button in App1.exe is pressed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499%28VS.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the window-handle of your app2.exe window and then use [BringWindowToTop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632673%28VS.85%29.aspx) on that handle.

You can find an (VB) example here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186431

Comment: MFC is just a wrapper on top of pure API calls, there should be no problems.
Maybe you need to call `ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOW)` on the window handle first since `BringWindowToTop` just `uncovers any window that is partially or completely obscured by other windows`.
Edit: there are also MFC Versions of FindWindow and BringWindowToTop which "work" with CWnd classes.

Answer (score 2):

Use [BringWindowToTop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632673%28VS.85%29.aspx). If you need to find the window handle first, use [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499%28VS.85%29.aspx).